# im working with the hair curve and trying to attach the curve to a new mesh

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, surface-deform

I created a hair curve on a mesh and im trying to add the curve to a new mesh. when trying to play with the curve and make it look better a node show an error:

```
Evaluated surface missing attribute: "rest_position".
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Are there any other modifiers before this geometry nodes modifier (Including other geometry nodes) ? Or any shape keys?

Comment: no I checked, not unless they are hidden somewhere.

Comment: I was able to recreate your error by using shape keys. But I don't know about modifiers. viz why I asked if there were any other modifiers or shape keys

Comment: And yes I am talking about modifiers and shape keys on the face model

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get past that error is to simply add empty hair to the mesh. You can delete it right after. That clears up the rest position error.

Then you will get another error *Curves are not attached to any UV map.* Well they are if you set up the curves with the surface and UV map filled in.

Just select the curves and go to sculpt mode. Under *Curves*, select *Snap to nearest surface*.

That clears up the UV map error and you are done.

I put up a short video of all the steps at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svyoFbmv5VM